# Rails: Change devise_invitable message - "The invitation token provided is not valid!"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I would like to change the default invalid invite token message for devise_invitable, but I'm not sure where to go in order to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the README](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#i18n):

> To customize your app, you can modify the generated locale file:
>
> ```
> en:   
>   devise:
>     invitations:
>       send_instructions: 'An invitation email has been sent to %{email}.'
>       invitation_token_invalid: 'The invitation token provided is not valid!'
>       updated: 'Your password was set successfully. You are now signed in.'
>       updated_not_active: 'Your password was set successfully.'
> ```

This file should be in your app's `config/locales` directory.

Comment: Thanks a million! By any chance do you know if it is possible to spread a message over multiple lines?

Comment: Yes, but that's purely a YAML file syntax question. If you google how to do that, you'll see there are actually several ways to achieve this.